# Remix deployment fails in Vercel but works fine in development - 'AbortController' not found

Tags: typescript, vercel, remix.run

I'm still fairly green when it comes to React and need some help figuring this out. Can anyone figure out why this fails when deploying to Vercel?

I haven't used `AbortController` explicitly anywhere so assume that maybe its related to one of the packages installed?

Repo: [Github Repo](https://github.com/danmeldominique/fem-country-app)

The project runs fine in development

```json
//tsconfig.json
{
  "include": ["remix.env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ES2022"],
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "strict": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./app/*"]
    },

    // Remix takes care of building everything in `remix build`.
    "noEmit": true
  }
}
```

```json
//package.json
{
  "name": "country-app",
  "private": true,
  "sideEffects": false,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npm run build:css && remix build",
    "build:css": "tailwindcss -o ./app/tailwind.css",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run dev:css\" \"remix dev\"",
    "dev:css": "tailwindcss -i ./app/global.css -o ./app/tailwind.css --watch",
    "start": "remix-serve ./build/index.js",
    "typecheck": "tsc"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.7.17",
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.0.18",
    "@remix-run/css-bundle": "^2.0.0",
    "@remix-run/node": "^2.0.0",
    "@remix-run/react": "^2.0.0",
    "@remix-run/serve": "^2.0.0",
    "clsx": "^2.0.0",
    "concurrently": "^8.2.1",
    "isbot": "^3.6.8",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "remix-utils": "^6.6.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@remix-run/dev": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.20",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "prettier": "^3.0.3",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "18"
  }
}
```

```
file:///var/task/build/server-build-nodejs-eyJydW50aW1lIjoibm9kZWpzIn0.mjs:2
  AbortController as NodeAbortController,
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Named export 'AbortController' not found. The requested module '@remix-run/node' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.
CommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export, for example using:

import pkg from '@remix-run/node';

    at ModuleJob._instantiate (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:124:21)
    at async ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:190:5)
RequestId: 12ff4058-63d5-40e3-8dde-8394bd9eb5a2 Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1
Runtime.ExitError
```

I've tried downgrading both remix and nodejs in case that something shipped in those packages was broken but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be an issue with Vercel - The `@remix-run/dev` package used by their adapter was still on `1.19.3`. They've now updated it to `2.0.0` and the deployment is working as expected.